# Como mostrar 1 millon de filas usando bootstrap-table.js

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy mostrando una tabla usando Bootstrap-table.js, con 10000 registros funciona pero cuando trato de mostrar mas registros (1 millon), intenta cargar y al cabo termina y no muestra.

La tabla tiene las siguiente opciones definidas:

```
 data-toolbar="#toolbar"
 data-url="http://localhost/proyecto/dame_registros"
 data-search='true'
 data-toggle='mi-tabla'
 data-show-toggle='true'
 data-show-columns='true'
 data-show-refresh='true'
 data-show-pagination-switch='true'
 data-pagination='true'
 data-page-list='[5, 10, 20, ALL]'
 data-sort-name='received'
 data-sort-order='desc'
```

Y la llamada en el archivo js es como sigue:

```
$('#mi-tabla').bootstrapTable({
    columns: [
            {
                field: 'id',
                title: 'ID',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle'
            },
            {
                field: 'received',
                title: 'Received',
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true,
                valign: 'middle'
            },
            {
                field: 'firstname',
                title: 'Firstname',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle'
            },
            {
                field: 'lastname',
                title: 'Lastname',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle'
            }
    ]
});
```

Estoy atento a cualquier idea, solución o sugerencia.

Comment: tienes que esperar mas tiempo ya que 1 millón es demasiado, por otro lado te invito a que conozcas como funciona la comunidad visitando la [presentación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). A continuación, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta siguiendo las [directrices de calidad](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A través de cual options aumento el tiempo de espera del bootstrap-table?

Comment: ¿Tiene sentido mostrar esa cantidad de registros de un solo golpe? De ser afirmativa la respuesta, me gustaría saber por qué :D saludos

Comment: Si necesito mostrarlos todo, por supuesto pero paginando, es decir, de 10 en 10 o de 100 en 100, pero todos. Por lo sugerido en los comentarios revise el bootstrap-table.js y existe una opción para hacer el paginado desde el servidor (sidePagination: 'server'), dicha opción envía en el objeto Request al server limit y offset. De esta forma el problema queda resuelto. En mi caso no resuelvo porque estoy usando MongoDB y el limit del mongo solo admite un parámetro, no admite offset.

Comment: En MongoDB puedes usar [`skip()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) para "simular" un `offset`. Pero con una cantidad grande de datos puede sufrir el rendimiento por cómo funciona.

Answer (score 2):

La idea principal de Bootstrap es tener una presentación homogénea en dispositivos de diversos tamaños.  Tratar de mostrar una tabla de 10,000 registros utilizando Bootstrap con paginación en el cliente ya me parece extremo, no se diga 1,000,000 de registros.

Lo mejor en todo caso es tratar de minimizar la cantidad de registros que se deben cargar en el cliente, ya sea a través de filtrado o paginación en el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Incluso un millón de registros es demasiado, consumirá demasíada memoria en el navegador y terminará seguramente por no renderizar. Si guardas esa información en un archivo de texto podrás darte cuenta del peso, si hablamos que pueda llegar a pesar hasta 1 GB el notepad no será capaz de abrirlo.

Siempre será mejor paginar en el servidor cuando se trata de una alta cantidad de registros.